# My.Resources in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, my.resources

Is there a way to access My.Resources thru Xaml?

Like this

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImage,
    Source={x:Static my:Resources},
    Converter={StaticResource MyBitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" />
```

This is the error I get:
**\Application.xaml(122,36): error MC3029: 'my:Resources' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.**

The above doesn't work of course.

NOTE: The converter is for illustration only.

---

### Update:

I thought about 1 idea, which might be a good approach if it will work, I created a wrapper class for the resources:

```
Public Class Resources
    Public Shared ReadOnly m_Resources As New Resources
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Resources() As Resources
        Get
            Return m_Resources
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property MyResources(ByVal name As String) As Object
        Get
            Return My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And then in my binding I try to access it like so:

```
<Setter Property="ImageSource"
Value="{Binding MyResources[Ok], Source={x:Static src:Resources.Resources}}"/>
```

But I still get the following message:

**System.Windows.Data Error: 16 : Cannot get 'MyResources' value (type 'Object') from '' (type 'Resources'). BindingExpression:Path=MyResources[Ok]; DataItem='Resources' (HashCode=59109011); target element is 'Image' (Name='btnOk'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource') TargetParameterCountException:'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.**

BTW, I placed a test MessageBox in the MyResources Getter, and it seems the property is not accessed at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that by default, the tool that generates code for the Resources.resx file is `VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator` ("Custom tool" property of the project item). This tool generates a Module in which the resource properties are internal (Friend), so the StaticExtension can't access it. To solve that problem, you should change the custom tool for Resources.resx to `PublicVbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator`, which will generate public members.

Also, a VB module is roughly equivalent to a static (Shared) class, so there is no instance of Resources that could be used as the source of the binding, so you can't specify a Path for the binding. You should set the binding source directly to the property you want :

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static my:Resources.MyImage},
    Converter={StaticResource MyBitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" />
```

Note: there is another pair of tools available to generate the code for a resource file : `ResXFileCodeGenerator` and `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. These tools generate a class instead of a module.

EDIT: The namespace mapping to use is the following :

```
xmlns:myRes="clr-namespace:YourApplicationName.My.Resources"
```

Comment: I checked and the generator was PublicVbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator.
Anyhow, I don't think the problem from security reasons, Friend is accessible from within the assembly. I think the problem is My.Resources is a namespaces while My.Resource.TheResource is a property, there ain't no class here, take a look at he error I quote above and you will see that this is the reason.
Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: There's *always* a class in .NET... well, in that case that's a module, but it's almost the same as a static class. I think your namespace mapping is incorrect, see my updated answer

Comment: You're the Man.

I thought since the Module is hidden (HideModuleNameAttribute), it won't work.
What I've learn from here is always give it a shot, even you won't kill anything...

Comment: The thing that worked is the "EDIT: The namespace mapping to use is the following :"

Answer (score 3):

Change access modifier of my.resources from freind to public in my.project resources tab.