# Data binding window title to application resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Currently I'm doing it so:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = Properties.Resources.WindowName;
    }
```

How to do the same through the WPF binding?

EDIT: It still doesn't work in XAML.
Environment:VS2010, .NET 4.0, Windows 7.
Reproduction steps:
Create class library ClassLibrary1 with code:

```
 namespace ClassLibrary1
 {
    static public class Class1
    {
        static public string Something
        {
            get { return "something"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Create WPF windows application in VS2010 .NET 4.0.
Edit main window's XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ahtranslator.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:ClassLibrary1="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary1;assembly=ClassLibrary1" 
    Title="{Binding Source={x:Static ClassLibrary1:Class1}, Path=Something}"
    Height="350" Width="525" Icon="/ahtranslator;component/Icon1.ico"    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" ShowInTaskbar="False" DataContext="{Binding}">
```

...

Compilation error message:
MainWindow.xaml(7,130): error MC3029: 'ClassLibrary1:Class1' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.

Also I found this topic [My.Resources in WPF XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420034/my-resources-in-wpf-xaml).
And it seems all should work but it doesn't.

Microsoft doesn't give description for this error message. Only another topic in help forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4fe7d58d-785f-434c-bef3-31bd9e400691, which doesn't help either.

Comment: The path in this case should be inside the `x:Static` as the property is static, i.e. `{Binding Source={x:Static ClassLibrary1:Class1.Something}}`, see the syntax on the [reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx). I also updated my answer which was misguided...

Answer (score 10):

In code it would look like this i think:

```
Binding titleBinding = new Binding("WindowName");
titleBinding.Source = Properties.Resources;
this.SetBinding(Window.Title, titleBinding);
```

This only makes sense if changes may occur to the title and the binding will be notified of those changes (`WindowName` has to either be a Dependency Property or `Resources` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

If `Properties` is a namespace (as would be the case with the default VS-generated properties) you need to declare it somewhere using `xmlns` & use [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx):

```
<Window
   ...
   xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:App.Properties"
   Title="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.WindowName}}">
```

Another note: If you use the managed resources of Visual Studio you need to make sure that the access modifier of the properties is `public`, default is `internal` which will throw an exception since binding only works for public properties.

Comment: Thanks. Your last suggestion is my case, but it doesn't work. Please see EDIT: of my post. I've made it as clear as I could imagine: moved the class to different assembly and so on.

Comment: I edited my answer to give more suggestions, hopefully some of this fits your problem.

Comment: The code behind method you list first does not work. You cannot set `Properties.Resources` as a binding source. "...Resources is a type, which is not valid in the given context" I tried specifying the resource key there, and it accepts it, but the binding fails. Text shows nothing

Comment: (Update) So I find myself in the same situation and stumbled upon the same question... This time the binding works, but doesn't update (when specifying a resource key) - I still can't set Properties.Resources as a binding source, and receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

just remove this:

```
... ;assembly=ClassLibrary1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the access modifier of the resource from internal to public?

I have just had some problem with that right now.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Has been impossible to load the configuration information.
    /// </summary>
    internal static string ERROR_NoConfigurationLoaded {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("ERROR_NoConfigurationLoaded", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

to

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Has been impossible to load the configuration information.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ERROR_NoConfigurationLoaded {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("ERROR_NoConfigurationLoaded", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have done it. Kindly look at the source code of ClassLibrary1
of my question. There is all public.

Answer (score -1):

I actually have the Title in a static resource defined at the top of the application and I bind the Title and anything else I want to it

```
<s:String x:Key="ApplicationName">My Application</s:String>
```

Comment: Which is the namespace used for s?

Comment: Sorry, `s` is a common namespace for system `xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib`